# Vim - delay when exiting visual mode

Tags: vim, delay

If I press ESC to exit Visual Mode after I select some text, there's a noticeable delay before the text gets unselected and I'm returned to Normal Mode (even if I only select 1-2 characters). Can this delay be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be caused by  being mapped to some additional functionality.  For example, I use the tabbar plugin and it maps 0-9 to switch to the number buffer.  Whenever a key is mapped to additional functionality like this, vim waits a few seconds after it is pressed to see if you're going to press any additional keys.

To see if  has any additional mappings, run `:map` and look for `<Esc>` in the first column.  When ran without any parameters, `:map` will list all the custom mappings.  If you want to list only the mappings while in visual mode, run `:vmap`.

If  does have additional mappings, I do not know of a way to remove the pause, besides removing the mappings.  The pause is necessary for vim to unambiguously know what action you intend it to take.

Comment: In VT100-like terminals (including Xterm/Rxvt/PuTTY/GNOME Terminal), `Esc` is also the prefix for all special keys, including even the arrow keys.

Comment: @grawity: True, but Vim uses different timeout values for those escape sequences than it does for mappings, so the handling of those escape sequences usually does not cause the problem reported here. See `:help 'timeout'`.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Now I only have to find which are those mappings that are interfering with my usage.

Answer (score 0):

I have no mapping bound to <ESC> globally or for Visual mode (calling :verbose vmap <ESC> gives no results) but there is still a significant delay when exiting Visual mode. Even on fresh installs with no vimrc the delay is present. Using <C-c> does exit visual mode without delay.

Since I don't like pressing <C-c> to exit any mode, I currently map <ESC> to <C-c> in visual mode. This exits visual mode using  <ESC> without any delay.

```
:vmap <ESC> <C-c>
```

Or put the following line in your vimrc

```
vnoremap <ESC> <C-c>
```

This will not work if you do have global or visual mode mappings bound to <ESC>.

Answer (score -2):

What you can do still, is using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit Visual mode, That should avoid the delay.